# node.jsでgit clone xxx出来ません。

Tags: git, node.js

初心者です。
わかる方教えていただけると本当に助かります！

node.jsをインストールしまして、以下のコマンドを入れるとこんな感じで表示されます。node.jsで動作保証しています。
どうしたら解決できますでしょうか。

```
git clone xxx

git clone xxx
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: `node` が実行できるのは JavaScript です。`git clone xxx` というのはシェル（sh、bash など）で `git` を実行するためのコマンド行ですので、`node` に渡しても、構文エラーになります。シェルに入力して実行して下さい。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます！試してみます！！